# Disable Evince thumbnails preview sidebar (Side Pane)

Tags: evince

Evince places left sidebar widget which placeholder for index and thumbnails (they call it **Side Pane**). It can be easy closed by clicking on **X** GUI button or **F9** keyboard button and this changes saved across document opening.

Index is useful feature, but thumbnails eat space and slowdown scrolling dramatically.

Is it possible hide **side pane** by default? Or better only in case when there are no index?[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A workaround.

Open up any pdf and then manually close the sidebar.
Then go to `Edit`->`Save current settings as Default` or the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

Now everytime you open any PDF, the sidepane will be hidden by default.
You can view it again by going to `View`->`Side Pane` or pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>.

*Tested in Ubuntu 14.04, Evince 3.10.3*

Comment: I accept your answer, even if in future someone provide full solution. Thanks for support!

Comment: @antimirov Cool. Thats why we are here.